# Can we upload a file on ftp server outside its default directory?

Tags: java, maven, ftp

I have created a sample Java Web Application in spring boot and inside Pom.xml I am using Maven Wagon to ftp my project's war file on FTP server.

But, Maven Wagon uploads war file into default folder of FTP server. I want Maven Wagon to uplad the war file into some other directory on FTP server for e.g Tomcat Web-apps directory.

Please tell if it is possible. If yes then what changes need to make in Maven Wagon configuration

Answer (score 1):

Don't have/know Maven Wagon, but code that takes an FTP URL will usually take the folder/file name as part of the URL.

Since the file name is define elsewhere, specify the target folder in the URL:

```xml
<url>ftps://secure.example.com/put/my/file/here</url>
```